# Object Filter in SSIS Salesforce Source

Tags: soql, integration, filters, systemmodstamp

I need to move all records from salesforce to a DWH using SSIS.

After the initial run I need to move only the records that either got inserted or updated after the last run into SFDC.

I learnt that SystemModstamp changes everytime a modification/Insert occurs.

Now how do I retrieve only the latest records using the object filter option available with salesforce Source Component provided by CozyRoc. ?

I've a Audit Table which stores the LOG Details of the package like PACKAGE_START_TIME,END_TIME etc...

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

LAST_WEEK ; LAST_N_DAYS:n ; N_DAYS_AGO:n are some of the Criteria's you can use while filtering in salesforce source...

SystemModstamp>LAST_WEEK
Check the below link for more:

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hmINAAY